# How to solve IllegalArgumentException error?

Tags: java, r, docker, shinyproxy

I am trying to deploy my R application using ShinyProxy and docker. As soon as run the command, java -jar I get a nested exception in docker terminal stating Illegal argument exception. I am attaching the last traceback error. I referred https://www.databentobox.com/2019/11/05/deploy-r-app-with-shinyproxy/ tutorial for deploying R application. Any suggestion on how to overcome this error?

```
    java -jar shinyproxy-2.3.0.jar

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An HTTPS URI for DOCKER_HOST must be provided to use Docker client certificates
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.<init>(DefaultDockerClient.java:441) ~[docker-client-8.15.2.jar!/:8.15.2]
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient$Builder.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:3194) ~[docker-client-8.15.2.jar!/:8.15.2]
    at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.docker.AbstractDockerBackend.initialize(AbstractDockerBackend.java:83) ~[containerproxy-0.8.3.jar!/:0.8.3]
    at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.ContainerBackendFactory.createInstance(ContainerBackendFactory.java:83) ~[containerproxy-0.8.3.jar!/:0.8.3]
    at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.ContainerBackendFactory.createInstance(ContainerBackendFactory.java:36) ~[containerproxy-0.8.3.jar!/:0.8.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:141) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you check the "Setting up Docker" section in the setup preparation in the documents? you need to have a docker host setup correctly in C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json file

Comment: @debugger89 Yes .Actually I didnt have docker folder in ProgramData folder so I manually created the docker folder and created daemon.json file but it didnt help

Comment: You have to have Docker installed and configured in your machine. Make sure to follow the setup steps provided in the documentation. https://www.databentobox.com/2019/11/05/deploy-r-app-with-shinyproxy/

Comment: @debugger89 I have docker toolbox installed but for some reason it is not present in ProgramData folder and hence I have to manually create docker folder in ProgramData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me by degrading shinyproxy version to 2.0.0 from 2.3.0.